# Change ImageView image in Java on Android

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

Following steps:

1. I create dynamically an ImageView and set it to a bitmap that I have downloaded from server previously. The image is display small as a thumbnail by scaling it down using setLayoutParams without changing its real size. I have a horizontal LinearLayout in my main XML layout file on top of the display that gets populated with such thumbnails. Just imagine a row of thumbnails on top of the display. **This works!**
2. In the main XML layout file I have a bigger ImageView below the LinearLayout (as described above) that should show the big version of the thumbnail that I click. So somehow I must manage to assign the bitmap in the thumbnail ImageView to the bigger ImageView. It is not possible to simply to this: bigImageView = imageViewArray[i];

Can you please let me know how this assignment can be done?

Here is the main XML layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".GalleryWithBaseadapter"
    android:background="#000000">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalContainer"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="120dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/imgLinearLayout"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </LinearLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/myProgressBar"
        android:visibility="visible"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:max="100"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:text="Click Me"
        android:onClick="onClickButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bigImage"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you for advice!

Comment: imageView1.setImageDrawable(imageView2.getDrawable())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
bigImageView.setImageDrawable(imageViewArray[i].getDrawable());
```

By the way you should set the large image from the file source and load small scaled versions of the images into your thumbnail list to avoid memory problems.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ImageView bigImage = ...
ImageView[] smallImages = ...


public void setSmallToBig(int positionInSmallArray){
    Drawable d = smallImages[positionInSmallArray].getDrawable();
    bigImage.setDrawableImage(d);
}
```